# Real Time Users Do Not Reflect In The Demographics

Tags: google-analytics

I used a server side analytics code , in php to integrate Google Analytics with my website.

```
 use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

    // Initilize GA Tracker
    $tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('UA-XXXXXX', 'XXXXX.com');

    // Assemble Visitor information
    // (could also get unserialized from database)
    $visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
    $visitor->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $visitor->setUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $visitor->setScreenResolution('1024x768');

    // Assemble Session information
    // (could also get unserialized from PHP session)
    $session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();

    // Assemble Page information
    $page = new GoogleAnalytics\Page($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $page->setTitle('My Page');

    // Track page view
    $tracker->trackPageview($page, $session, $visitor);
```

The thing is, yesterday it was showing real time users on the website but today the total visits shown on website is Zero.
Is there a problem with this server side implementation. ?

Answer (score 0):

Recently Google has launched API - Google Real Time API which provide the similar functionality. try - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide